# Linking LDA topics to the input documents

Tags: nlp, topic-model, lda, gensim

I am new to LDA topic modelling. I am using gensim and am able to generate topics that make sense. Using 25k of documents, I can also print them using `print_topics`. I am aware that we need use the generated model to classify any new document. I would like to know the topics for each training document. Do I have to treat them as new documents to find their topics?

```
lda.print_topics(num_topics=22, num_words=8)
```

Comment: Could you add some more code, i.e. the model you estimate. So people can follow your approach and make meaningful suggestions. Which platform are you on? Python? You could add a tag.

Comment: Step 18 of [Machinelearningplus](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/) answers your question, I think